# How to get src image and text from html string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How get src image and text (*underline*) from html string ?

src and style are fixed.

<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><div>   **src="http://and_Snorkel_Club.jpg"** **style**="width: 300px; height: 225px; float: right; margin: 10px;" **During spring break, the Mount Olive College SCUBA/Snorkel Club traveled to Crystal River, Florida to expand their knowledge on aquatic life and to obtain their Open Water certification**.</div></div></div></div>

Comment: Are you getting this HTML from somewhere?  Or is it guaranteed never to change?

Comment: I get this html from rss feed and Yes it's format not changed.src and style of text are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get specific value from `HTML` content you need to **Parse** `HTML` content by using [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). Here's the [documentation with exmple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios). (*in this documentation you will find how to get **src***)

**In your case you use: (***by using Hpple***)**

```
TFHpple *dataParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:placesData];

NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='field-item even']/div/";
NSArray *listOfdata= [dataParser searchWithXPathQuery: XpathQueryString];
```

My code will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><div> src="http://and_Snorkel_Club.jpg" *style*="width: 300px; height: 225px; float: right; margin: 10px;" During spring break, the Mount Olive College SCUBA/Snorkel Club traveled to Crystal River, Florida to expand their knowledge on aquatic life and to obtain their Open Water certification.</div></div></div></div>";

NSMutableString *imagLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:htmlString];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"http://" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:@""" *style" intoString:imgLink];

NSLog(@"%@", imgLink);
```

Similarly, you can apply this method to fetch other text of the HTML String. or Else you could use the way iPatel have shown.